# Is there any value in Open sourcing your for fun projects

Tags: open-source

I have written a bunch of fun for me projects and have shown them to friends and such.  Is there any value in doing the work and making these projects open source since the interest and usefulness limited.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Sure!**

- Limited usefulness can be extended by others.
- Others might need exactly the same sort of code or it could be used as teaching material.
- Due to huge internet demographics there is sure someone who is interested.

**On the other hand:**

- OpenSource code should be well documented or commented.
- Code should be understandable and readable.
- Code should be working.

**Keep in mind:**

- Others may tidy up your code if they got your mind.
- Others may optimize your code and teach you something.

Comment: that sounds a bit like there is no need to comment/document closed source code...

Comment: Sorry, but no - you need to. Umm... You have to actually, but documentation/comments are much more needed in OpenSource because even beginner might look at your code, and there will be no one who might introduce you to the code, unlike in companies where ClosedSource is written.

Answer (score 10):

**Absolutely**

It bare minimum, it showcases your work. At best, you'll generate interest, people will fork your project and potentially turn it into something you never even considered creating :)

Answer (score 5):

The real value of open-source is how it can be used to learn, in the community it creates and the value that community brings to it through bug-fixes and enhancements.

If you want to help others learn what you know and wish to learn from the collective knowledge of other programmers, open-source is a great way.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. If nothing else, you have solved the problem of storing and sharing the code when you need it.